# Read text from focused text field from any top most application using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want my AppleScript to operate on the text entered in the current focused text field of the top most application.

Using

```
tell application "System Events"
    set topProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
end tell
```

I can get the top most process. How can I get its focused text field?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what application you are running on. If the text is always going to highlighted within the App then you can do something like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Name of App" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
```

This generally works when the App you are working with is "active"...